# resizing height of textview to match content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview, settext

I am adding content to the textView below dynamically and it works.  The only problem is, I only see one line of text.  If I set the text of textView to something that is 25 lines long via the layout.xml or using a string, and then replace that with new text dynamically, then the new text will only be 25 lines long, even if its actually 50.  I set minLines to a high number but that is sloppy code to me.  Any idea on what I'm missing here?

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `fill_parent` and `match_parent` are synonymous. `match_parent` replaced `fill_parent` because it more accurately reflected how the view is sized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Try using:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This will let the TextView expand to the height required by its contents. At the same time, the ScrollView will take care of what is show depending on the scroll position.